# Check Browser Compatibilty error with Dreamweaver CS5.5

Tags: css, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I am having problems with the Check Browser Compatibilty function, it seems to pick up the issues in an HTML file but ignores errors in CSS files.

I have run the check on Dreamweaver CS4 and it work fine.

Example of a simple CSS file that fails.

@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

h2

{

color: transparent ;

}

Should give the following error -   Unsupported value: 'transparent' ;

It is running on a PC, Version 11.5 Build 5344.

Has anyone encountered this? if so any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why are you expecting it to give an error? The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent) says that `transparent` is a valid value for the `color` property:

> CSS3 extends the color value to include the ‘transparent’ keyword to
>   allow its use with all properties that accept a `<color>` value.

The [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) also agrees that your example is valid CSS.

Comment: This was just an example, 'transparent' is an issue with older browsers. A more extreme example is a missing end curly brace, you should get a parse style error but I don't.

Comment: @ZosoOfZep - Yes, but it is valid CSS. Maybe it should generate a warning, but not an error. If an actual syntax error doesn't generate an error then something is wrong. Maybe you should post this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) as it seems to be related more to the application rather than a specific programming problem.

Comment: OK lets call it a warning, it's still not flagged up. The example with out the end curly brace is an error.